# How to set the Z-Index of a Label Control in Code?

Tags: z-index

How to set the Z-Index of a Label control in Code? 
I could see the option in XAML's property, but in code, I can't find something like:

> `Label1.SetZIndex // don't have this..`

I looked through the Intellisence option, but I found nothing related to Z-index.
I am placing a Label on a TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Canvas.SetZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setzindex%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)